# What's the correct way to filter and keep the original results with Redux

Tags: redux

I'm looking for the "correct" way to filter the original state.

**State**

```
{
  searchText: '',
  items: [
    {name: 'Tom'},
    {name: 'Larry'},
    {name: 'Harry'}
  ]
}
```

**Reducer**

```
    const filterText = action.text.toLowerCase();
    const filteredResults = state.items.filter((item) => {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) > -1
    })

    const newState = { items: filteredResults , searchText: action.text }
    return newState
```

**Container**

```
return this.props.people.items.map((person) => {
     return(
       <li
         key={person.name}
         onClick={() => this.props.selectPerson(person)}
        >{person.name}</li>
     )
   })
```

However if I clear the text input I've obviously removed the items with .filter() I basically need on the keystroke to search all results but not remove from the original state.

I have a solution, and store an additional piece of data on the store and then add the results into the items array.

```
initialItems: [...],
items: [...]
```

However as mentioned I'm looking for the correct way to filter my results and I'm not sure if this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is just one of the solutions to do this. IMO there are no "correct" ways because every implementation will have its pros and cons :)

However, a "cleaner" solution with eventually better performance results that comes to my mind is to use a `selector` in `mapStateToProps` which will filter out the items according to the `searchText`. In practice it would be just moving your code from the `reducer` to a `selector`.

```
const filterItems = state =>
  state.items.filter(item =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(state.searchText.toLowerCase())
  );

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  filteredItems: filterItems(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

You could do this even better by using `reselect` - https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Comment: Perfect, I needed to tweak it a little as it wasn't returning my data. 

const data = state.items.filter(item =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(state.searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1
  );
  return data; 
but it works exactly how I needed it to, thank you.